# Get check Box value from Java Script function

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, checkbox

I have some `checkboxes` as shown

```
</tr>
<td style="padding-left: 10px" width="70px">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytLek" runat="server" class="llogariDyt" GroupName="Monedha" Text="Lek" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" OnClick="ChkValidate()" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="images/eagle-clipart-albanian-7.jpg" width="24px" height="15px" />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytCAD" runat="server" GroupName="Monedha" Text="CAD" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" class="llogariDyt" OnClick="ChkValidate()" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="images/CAD.png" width="24px" height="15px" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytEU" runat="server" GroupName="Monedha" Text="EUR" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" class="llogariDyt" OnClick="ChkValidate()" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="images/eu.png" width="24px" height="15px" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I want to limit the user to select not more than 2 of them. I am using a java Script function, but I cant tell why the function is called but enters only in `alert(1)` and doesn't get the values of my check boxes.
I am calling them the wrong way or something?

```
function ChkValidate() {

    var NewCount = 0

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("chkDytLek").checked = true) {
        NewCount = NewCount + 1
    }
    alert(2);
    if (document.getElementById("chkDytUSD").checked = true) {
        NewCount = NewCount + 1
    }
    alert(3);
    if (document.getElementById("chkDytEUR").checked = true) {
        NewCount = NewCount + 1
    }

    if (document.getElementById("chkDytCAD").checked = true) {
        NewCount = NewCount + 1
    }

    if (document.getElementById("chkDytCHF").checked = true) {
        NewCount = NewCount + 1
    }

    if (NewCount == 3) {
        alert('Pick Just Two Please')
        document.forms;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(a = true)` does not do what you think it does. It's not _checking_ if a is true, it's _assigning_ the value true to a (and returning the result of the operation, which is also true, so the `if()` condition will always be satisfied). You want to use `if(a === true)`, or simply `if(a)`.

Comment: @JeremyThillei changet all the if conditions in alert(1); if (document.getElementsById("chkDytLek").checked == true) { NewCount = NewCount + 1 } but still nothing

Answer (score 1):

that is because of the single '=' in your if conditions.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("chkDytLek").checked = true)
```

should be :

```
if (document.getElementById("chkDytLek").checked == true)
```

Comment: i changet all the if conditions in alert(1); if (document.getElementsById("chkDytLek").checked == true) { NewCount = NewCount + 1 } but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

First thing `chkDytLek` is not class in your code It is an `Id` and also single `=` used for assign not for comparing

Replace code and assign correct `classes` and `Id's`

```
document.getElementById("chkDytLek").checked == true
```

Note -> 
`getElementById` will give a single dom element because Id is unique in Dom
`getElementsByClassName` will give you an array so you need to check like this for class

```
document.getElementsByClassName("someclass").checked = true
```

If you want above functionality with class name then check this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14967895/6236938

http://jsfiddle.net/4mYbD/3/

Comment: yes it is a mistake a forgot to correct before posting the code, i replaced it with      alert(1);
                  if (document.getElementsById("chkDytLek").checked == true)
                  { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }   but still nothing. how is using getElementsByClassName identifying which check box is checked and which not? that was the reason i am trying to use getElementById

Comment: Ok if you want do  with `getElementsByClassName  ` then you can do with array index's As I mentioned above `getElementsByClassName ` will return array

Comment: I update my answer with some link I will suggest you to do this with class not by id.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve with one condition instead of multiple condition,

```
function ChkValidate() {
    var countClicks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length

    if(countClicks > 2){
      alert('Pick Just Two Please')
      document.forms;
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: using the  <INPUT name=ChkDytCHF type=checkbox value=Charity_profile onclick="return itemClicked(3)"> CHF tag is giving me problems with all the rest of code, and still not giving me what i want

Comment: @Lara Please check your checkbox whether you have given properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use this kind of code (shorter and more elegant) :

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox")

ChkValidate = () => {
 let checkedCount = checkboxes
           .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked) // Keeps only the checked ones
           .length
           
 console.log("checkedCount = ", checkedCount)
  
 if (checkedCount > 2) alert("Pick Just Two Please")
}

checkboxes.forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener("click", ChkValidate)) // Attach click events to nodes
checkboxes = Array.from(checkboxes) // Allows then to use .filter
```

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: using the <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/> gives me error in this line since i have a method that checks if one specific checkbox is checked or not bool monDytLek = ChkDytLek.Checked;

Answer (score 0):

> Issue is with you condition check expression. `=` is for **assigning** values from right to left for eg. `var x = 10;` here `10` is being assigned to `x` and for **comparision** `==` is used for eg. `if (x == y)`, here you're comparing if `x` equals `y`

```js
function changed(e){
  var message = e.target.checked ? ' is checked' : ' is unchecked';
  switch(e.target.id){
     case 'CheckBox1': alert(e.target.id + message); break;
     case 'CheckBox2': alert(e.target.id + message); break;
     case 'CheckBox3': alert(e.target.id + message); break;
     case 'CheckBox4': alert(e.target.id + message); break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" onClick="changed(event)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox2" onClick="changed(event)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox3" onClick="changed(event)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox4" onClick="changed(event)" />
```

and because

> `javascript` is **case sensitive** that means `hello` and `Hello` are different to it, and that's exactly where your issue lies.

```
if (document.getElementById("chkDytLek").checked == true) {
   /* your code */
}
```

should be changed to

```
if (document.getElementById("ChkDytLek").checked == true) {
   * your code */
}
```

the `parameters` should be exactly in same case as they actually are.

Comment: i followed your suggestion but still nothing

Comment: @Lara i edited and explained the scenario, please have a look

Comment: using the <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/> gives me error in this line since i have a method that checks if one specific checkbox is checked or not bool monDytLek = ChkDytLek.Checked;

Comment: forget the `input`s that should not be confused with, since you're using `.aspx`. As long as you're giving the proper `id`'s the `javascript` should serve  the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ChkValidate() {
  var aCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  
  if (count === 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < aCheckboxes.length; i++) {
      if (!aCheckboxes[i].checked) {
        aCheckboxes[i].disabled = true;
      }
    };
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < aCheckboxes.length; i++) {
      aCheckboxes[i].disabled = false;
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onChange="ChkValidate();" />
<input type="checkbox" onChange="ChkValidate();" />
<input type="checkbox" onChange="ChkValidate();" />
<input type="checkbox" onChange="ChkValidate();" />
```

Comment: using the <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/> gives me error in this line since i have a method that checks if one specific checkbox is checked or not bool monDytLek = ChkDytLek.Checked;

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("checkBoxparent").addEventListener("change", ChkValidate);
var checkBoxentry = []
function ChkValidate(e) {
    checkBoxentry.push(e.target.getAttribute("id"));
    if(checkBoxentry.length >= 3){
      alert("Please select only two");
      e.target.checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: Please add this id "checkBoxparent" to table tag in HTML file.

Comment: you mean this way?                                                                           <table id="checkBoxparent" border="0" > because still not working. should i change something in my check boxes tag also?

Comment: It will be great if u can share your code atleast checkbox container i mean either entire form or table code

Answer (score 0):

After searching and researching i found that the solution was pretty simple. In the check box tag i needed to add a client ID as Static and than the Java Script function worked perfectly.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytLek" runat="server" class="llogariDyt"                                
                                GroupName="Monedha" Text="Lek" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" onClick="ChkValidate()" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```